# PHP takes file as a directory?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have removed the php files extension som my files don't have the .php, but now some of my PHP code starts to think that it is a directory.

Look at this:

```
<?php
$currentDir = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
if ($currentDir == '/website/products') {
    echo '<li class="current"><a href="http://localhost/website/products">Products</a></li>';
}
else {
    echo '<li><a href="http://localhost/website/products">Products</a></li>';
}
```

Then if I have a file within the products folder called example.php then if I type example.php in the adress field it goes in the first one with class="current"

But if i type example in the adress field without the PHP extension, i get in else and don't get the `class="current"` :( :( :(

Can you help???

Comment: Have you tried echoing the value of $currentDir in the else?

Comment: Try `echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and `echo $currentDir` to debug your values.

Answer (score 0):

One option is add these extensions again and just use mod_rewrite for apache

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Yeah but i like to use the filenames without php extension.
Therefore I have this in my .htaccess file:

`# enable hidding PHP extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`